# What sound is /a/?

Tags: phonetics, vowels

Is it similar to /ʌ/ or is it more like /ɔ/ or is it something different? I've seen it combined with /ʌ/ several times in different phonetic scripts. Are the 2 similar or where they just lumped together out of laziness?

Comment: Are you talking about American English or British English (or some other kind of English)? And it would help us if you could remember in what context you've seen /a/ lumped with /ʌ/ ... in most dialects of English., /ʌ/, /ɔ/, and /a/ are quite different from each other.

Comment: American English. I've seen it mostly in adapted scripts for english like this one:https://alternatescriptbureau.wordpress.com/2020/03/27/arabic-script-for-english/ as well as other scripts from the same site. Both /a/ & /ʌ/ use 'ا' (alif).

Answer (score 1):

The /a/ phoneme represents the [open front unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_front_unrounded_vowel)
from FATHER and KHAN. If you have this, you do not have the next one. It can be found in some speakers from southern England. Other native speakers
use a back vowel here instead, /ɑ/, which means those with the back vowel can easily confuse hearing this one from speakers of southern English for the /æ/ phoneme.

The /ɑ/ phoneme represents the [open back unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_back_unrounded_vowel)
from FATHER and KHAN. It occurs in most native speakers who are not from southern English where
they use a front vowel here instead, /a/.

The /æ/ phoneme represents the [near-open front unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_back_unrounded_vowel)
from TRAP and CAT and HAM and MAN.
In some speakers from southern England it can be confused for their /a/ phoneme.
In some speakers from other parts of the world, including the southern United States and in the Inland North of the Great Lakes of the United
States and Canada, it can be confused for
their /ɛ/ phoneme, the [open-mid front unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel)
from DRESS and BET and HEM and MEN.

The /ʌ/ phoneme represents the [open-mid central unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-open_central_vowel)
from STRUT and RUN. It is the stressed version of schwa, /ə/, which is never stressed.

The /ə/ phoneme represents the [mid central unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid_central_vowel) schwa
from the first syllable of ABOUT and from the last syllable of COMMA.
It is the unstressed version of /ʌ/, which is always stressed.

The /ɔ/ phoneme represents the [open-mid back rounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_back_rounded_vowel)
from THOUGHT and CALL. Speakers from Western Pennsylvania use this rounded vowel for both COT and CAUGHT, DON and DAWN, while speakers from Southern California and many places west of the Mississippi have no rounded back vowel, so they use only the unrounded back FATHER vowel /ɑ/ for all such words as COT, CAUGHT, CLOTH, DON, DAWN, DOG, GONE — all without any rounding in their mouths. If you are such a speaker then this may be the source of your confusion, as Peter Shor has mentioned in comments.

Here’s a summary so you can see what contrasts with what, and how.

```
/a/  open       front    unrounded
/æ/  near-open  front    unrounded
/ɛ/  open-mid   front    unrounded
/ʌ/  open-mid   central  unrounded  stressed-only
/ə/  mid        central  unrounded  unstressed-only
/ɔ/  open-mid   back     rounded
/ɑ/  open       back     unrounded
```

Comment: Trying to answer this question without knowing which variety of English the OP is talking about makes it really challenging. If FATHER is the same as THOUGHT (which I'd guess is what he's referring to when he says he's read that /a/ is like /ɔ/) then your descriptions are off.

Comment: @PeterShor Hardly surprising if folks with the THOUGHT–CLOTH–FATHER–BOTHER–LOT–LOG–DOG–PALM–DON–DAWN  merger find themselves confused by phonetic transcriptions. :)

Comment: I've seen both /ɔ/ and /ɔː/. Is there a difference?

Comment: https://alternatescriptbureau.wordpress.com/2020/03/27/arabic-script-for-english/ considers them different sounds. /ɔ/ is اُ /ɔː/ اٌ so 'father' would be فُذأر, 'fall' would be فٌلّ.

Comment: ^ as in fɔðər vs fɔːl

Comment: @jastako I know what  *fall* is, but what does *fawther* mean?

Comment: @tchrist Do you mean fɔðər? That's the phonetic spelling of 'father'. Assuming that ɔ is an 'ah' & ɔː (with an ː) is 'aw' - which most sites I've seen say they are - *fawther* would use 'ɔː' instead of 'ɔ' so it would be 'fɔːðər'.

Comment: @jastako No sir, [fɔðər] is absolutely not the phonetic spelling of that word.The sound of [FATHER](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/father) has **no rounding** whatsoever. Follow the link: nobody says it that way anywhere. **/ɔ/ is *rounded***, a completely different phoneme, the one from [DAUGHTER](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/daughter). Also, the length of a sound is merely allophonic not phonemic in American English, so it doesn't go in slashes here.

Comment: @tchrist except it is. See the IPA for english. In American English THOUGHT is spelled with ɔ. & the 'er' sound is written as ər. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/English

Comment: @jastako **Where are you from** that you’ve conﬂated DAUGHTER’s ʀᴏᴜɴᴅᴇᴅ vowel [ɔ] with FATHER’s ᴜɴʀᴏᴜɴᴅᴇᴅ vowel [ɑ]⁈⁉ Nobody in North America has a trill [r] or ﬂap [ɾ] in those words, only ever an approximate like [ɹ, ɹ̩, ɚ]. Scots alone can have a “ﬂapped R” sound in [ˈfaˑðəɾ], but many use [ˈfäˑðəɹ] like us. Ireland sees [fað̞əɹ] and [ˈfäðɚ]; England's West Country [ˈfa̠ːðɹ̩] and its north [ˈfa̠ːðɚ]. London has [ˈfɑːð̞ə] whose “silent R” appears only in liaison, like Alabama’s [ˈfɑːðə] and Boston’s [ˈfäːðɜ̠]. The rest of North America has an unﬂapped approximate R: [ˈfɑˑðɹ̩], [ˈfäðɚ].

Comment: @tchrist We'll just have to disagree. I have never heard anyone from North America pronounce the 2 words differently.

Comment: @jastako Then you should listen to a million Americans saying [*daughter* with /ɔ/](https://youglish.com/pronounce/daughter/english/us?) versus them saying [*father* with /ɑ/](https://youglish.com/pronounce/father/english/us?). If you still cannot hear the difference, then it's you not them, because the vast majority of them say these two words’ stressed vowels quite differently. And you still haven't told us where you're from, which could explain this.  There are a few people who say *dahtter* and fewer still who say *fawther*, but these both exist.

Comment: May I ask a question here or do I have to ask it as a new question? (As I don't have much time I'm afraid I will ask then check your response later) Cambridge online dictionary gives /ˈfɑː.ðər/ for "father" whereas you say "The /ɑ/ phoneme represents the open back unrounded vowel from FATHER and KHAN. It occurs in most native speakers who are not from southern English where they use a front vowel here instead, /a/.". Cambridge gives /ɑ/ for father. Does it mean that Cambridge is inconsistent with its transcriptions please?

Comment: @Sphinx All that's happening there is that [different publishing houses follow different conventions for representing the same sounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation#Alternative_notation). There's a lot of convention and clumping, so you would really have to look at [a dialect's parallelogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_diagram) of measured sounds to know what is what. See the notes below [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonology#Vowels).

Comment: @Sphinx For actual measured values across dialects, see for example [name](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/name),
[calf](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/calf),
[salt](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/salt),
[daughter](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/daughter),
[cold](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/cold), [better](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/better),
[head](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/head),
[naked](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/naked).